# windows batch file errors out on variable name in if statement

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@IF [%PORT%] == [] ( 
@echo Error : Com port not specified 
goto end
) ELSE (
    IF  x%PORT:COM=%==x%PORT% (
        @echo ERROR: Com port name invalid
        goto end
    )
)
```

I get the error saying

> =PORT was unexpected at this time.

When the outer if statement is successful

Comment: I don't see anything here related to Powershell. Please don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: sorry, removed the tag

Comment: For safety please enclose your strings for comparison in doublequotes, `IF "%PORT%"==""` and `IF /I "x%PORT:COM=%"=="x%PORT%"`. For the former, I'd prefer `IF NOT DEFINED PORT` after having first ensured that it was with `SET "PORT="`.

Comment: now I get ( was unexpected at this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that line `IF  x%PORT:COM=%==x%PORT%` is parsed even when `PORT` is empty, and since [sub-string substitution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) is used, which is actually aborted with empty variables, the expanded line is invalid syntax.

To fix that, do not use `else`, but write it as a separate `if` statement, so it is not parsed if `PORT` is undefined:

```cmd
if not defined PORT ( 
    echo ERROR: COM port not specified
    goto end
)
if "%PORT:COM=%"=="%PORT%" (
    echo ERROR: COM port name invalid
    goto end
)
```

Additionally, I put quotation marks around the comparison expressions, which is recommended to avoid problems with special characters. Furthermore, to check whether the variable is empty, I used `if defined` instead of a comparison.